# Adding underbrace to certain parts of chemfig

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

So I am trying to create something like this with an underbrace. How should I do it? Also, how should the charge part be done as well? Please and thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning,decorations,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\begin{document}
\definesubmol{x}{-[:+30,.6]-[:-30,.6]}
\def\RED{\gdef\printatom##1{\color{red}\ensuremath{\mathrm{##1}}}}
\chemfig{!x!x!x!x!x!x!x!x(-[,,,,draw=none]\RED)(-[:30,.6,,,,,red](=[:90,.7,,,,,red]O)-[:-30,.8,,,,,,red]ONa)}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that there are more elegant ways, but you can add some anchors and draw the brace with `\chemmove`. However, I strongly recommend not to use the `\RED` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\begin{document}
\definesubmol{x}{-[:+30,.6]-[:-30,.6]}
\chemfig{@{l1}!x!x!x!x!x!x!x!x@{l2}(-[,,,,draw=none])(-[:30,.6,,,,,red](=[:90,.7,,,,,red]{\color{red}O})-[:-30,.8,,,,,,red]{\color{red}ONa})@{l3}}
\chemmove{%
\draw[-,thick,decorate,
    decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=3pt,raise=1.2ex,mirror}] 
    (l1|-l3) -- node[below=1.7ex,font=\sffamily\small] {Nonpolar tail} (l2|-l3);
\draw[-,thick,decorate,red,
    decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=3pt,raise=1.2ex,mirror}] 
    (l2|-l3) -- node[below=1.7ex,font=\sffamily\small] {Polar head}
    ([xshift=1em]l3.east);  }
\end{document}
```

[image]